# Wrap two different elements in the same div to all classes with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the following:

```
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents">
  <span><h3></h3></span>
  <span><img></span>
  <span><p></span>
</div>
```

To look like this:

```
<div class="contents">
  <div>
    <span><h3></h3></span>
    <span><img></span>
  </div>
  <span><p></span>
</div>
```

for each of the contents classes. My code:

```
var contents = $('.page').find('.contents');

var nestedContents = contents.find('span:nth-child(1)');
nestedContents.attr("id", 'h3-location');

var imgContents = contents.find('span:nth-child(2)');
imgContents.attr("id", 'img-location');

$('#img-location, #h3-location').wrap('<div class="groupedContent"></div>');
```

But all this is doing is wrapping the img and h3 spans in separate groupedContent divs. I have tried wrapAll and it takes ALL the img and h3 spans in the document and puts them in the one groupedContent div in the FIRST contents class. I can't put the img and h3 spans inside the one groupedContent div within each contents class.

Comment: Where are the close tags to the first 2 `<div class="content">'s?, at the bottom?

Comment: Oh my mistake, I'll add them in

Comment: what should happen to the extra `content` elements

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3prwm2ok/1/

Comment: The same thing should be happening for all the content elements ie they all have the same structure currently but should then all have the inner div wrapping img and h3.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JSFiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/h2awu27c/2/

With HTML code like so...

```
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents">
    <span><h3 id="h3-location">The H3</h3></span>
    <span><img id="img-location" /></span>
    <span><p>asd</p></span>
</div>
<div class="contents">
    <span><h3 id="h3-location">The H3 2</h3></span>
    <span><img id="img-location" /></span>
    <span><p>asd 2</p></span>
</div>
<div class="contents"></div>
```

To achieve with JS / Jquery, i.e. remove empty .contents divs and wrap the children h3 and img tag inside a groupedContent div:

```
<div class="contents">
    <div class="groupedContent">
        <span><h3 id="h3-location">The H3</h3></span>
        <span><img id="img-location" /></span>
    </div>
    <span><p>asd</p></span>
</div>
<div class="contents">
    <div class="groupedContent">
        <span><h3 id="h3-location">The H3 2</h3></span>
        <span><img id="img-location" /></span>
    </div>
    <span><p>asd 2</p></span>
</div>
```

Use:

```
$('.contents').each(function() {
    var $contents = $(this);

    if ($contents.is(':empty')) { 
        $contents.remove();
    }
    else
    {
        $contents.children('span:has(h3),span:has(img)').wrapAll('<div class="groupedContent"></div>');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [WrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) for the `div.content` rather than [.Wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/), then select the `h3` and `img` parent span tags again and wrapAll those:

```
$('div.contents span:nth-child(1),div.contents span:nth-child(2)').wrapAll('<div></div>')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x9asccrb/

Comment: wrapAll is taaking ALL the imgs and h3's in the document and nesting them in one div in the FIRST contents div only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .wrapAll() like below

```js
$('.page .contents').each(function() {
  var $contents = $(this);
  $contents.children('span:has(h3),span:has(img)').wrapAll('<div class="groupedContent"></div>')
})
```

```css
.contents {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
.groupedContent {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
}
span {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div class="contents">
    <span><h3></h3></span>
    <span><img src=""/></span>
    <span><p>some p</p>?</span>
  </div>
  <div class="contents">
    <span><h3></h3></span>
    <span><img src=""/></span>
    <span><p>some p</p>?</span>
  </div>
  <div class="contents">
    <span><h3></h3></span>
    <span><img src=""/></span>
    <span><p>some p</p>?</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: Your html is invalid, `span` can't have `p` as its descendant

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your request well, you need this:

**JS:**

```
var page = $('.page'),
    $contents = page.find('.contents:has(span)').contents(),
    item = $contents.wrapAll('<div class="groupedContent"></div>');

$('.groupedContent').clone().appendTo(page.find('.contents:empty'));
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="contents"></div>
    <div class="contents"></div>
    <div class="contents"> 
     <span><h3>H3</h3></span>
     <span><img src="#"/></span>
     <span><p>P</p></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So you take a content of a `div` which `:has` a `span`, and wrapping it in another `div.groupedContent`. Then you are cloning this wrapped content and appending it to the rest of `.contents` elements (`:empty divs`).

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hedgehog34/jm58zzew/)**

Hope this helps